# Where can I find detailed dimensions of aircraft panels?

Tags: flight-simulator

I'm thinking of building some of physical aspects of a flight simulator, such as the overhead panels and pedestal.

Is there a **publication available where I could find detailed dimensions of cockpit panel sizes** of say Boeing 737 and A320s? I've found some pictures online but they don't quite have the detail I would like. Google images shows a few results with detailed dimensions, so I'm wondering where they got theirs from... actual measurements perhaps? (there are photos of measurements, but i'd like something maybe a little more exact)  Is there maybe a standard size of these panels, also on the larger jets?

[image: A320 Overhead]

Sort of thing I'm looking for: 
[image: AP Dimensions]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There appears to be some (free) quality materials accessible through the download section of [Open Cockpit's Website](http://www.opencockpits.com/index.php/en/download/), including CAD (.dwg) files and drawings such as this [737 Overhead Panel](http://www.opencockpits.com/index.php/en/download/item/b737-overhead?category_id=48%20%22737%20Overhead).

(seem to have at least partially answered my own question, but a clear technical drawing if somebody could provide/suggest a source of one would be greatly appreciated)

Comment: You could try the manufacturer's parts or service manuals. The quality and precision of drawings contained in these may not be up to what you're looking for though so best to see if you can look through one before forking over the cash for it...

Answer (score 1):

A good start is to read the free and available military standards regarding Aircrew station design.

MIL-C-6781 : CONTROL PANEL, AIRCRAFT EQUIPMENT, RACK OR CONSOLE MOUNTED

[MS25212](https://quicksearch.dla.mil/qsDocDetails.aspx?ident_number=40767) : CONTROL PANEL, CONSOLE TYPE, AIRCRAFT EQUIPMENT, BASIC DIMENSIONS

MS25213 : CONTROL PANEL, CONSOLE TYPE, AIRCRAFT EQUIPMENT, TYPICAL INSTALLATION

MIL-DTL-7788 : PANELS, INFORMATION, INTEGRALLY ILLUMINATED

MS25212/MS25213 have drawings like the ones you request. They state that the nominal width of a type I standard panel shall be 5 3/4" 146.05 mm, and that the length of a type I panel shall be a multiple (between 3 and 24) of 3/8" 9.525 mm. They also state that the distance of the fastener holes center from the (nominal) width edges of the panel shall be .1925" ~4.9 mm, (c/c 5,365" ~136.3 mm), and from the height edges .562" ~14.3 mm (c/c multiple of 3/8" 9.525 mm).

Type II control panels are designed for specific purposes where one or more dimensions or features to qualify for being type I control panel cannot be used. Type II control panels shall be similar to type I control panels in all practicable aspects.

Regarding Boeing and Airbus the question is a bit harder. Both appears to derive their design from the military standard but to varying degree. So seems for example Boeing to be using a double standard width overhead center panel of 11 1/2", while Airbus are using a slightly larger dimension of (measured) 325 mm. Thou both are using the same (Dzus/DFCI) quarter turn fastener systems giving the length of the panels.