# Where can I go to sit in the cockpit of a Boeing?

Tags: passenger, boeing, boeing-737, cockpit, uk

This might sound like a silly question to some, but is it possible to go and sit in the cockpit of a Boeing 737, somewhere in the UK? (Otherwise in Europe, or beyond).

Maybe at a museum or something? I'm building a [currently tiny] home cockpit based on a 737, and I'd like to see how the real thing looks and feels.

I tried searching online, but I couldn't find anything.

Hope this isn't too dumb of a question, i.e. "not possible Jim!"

Comment: You might want to look at [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1527/where-can-i-find-detailed-dimensions-of-aircraft-panels), which has some links to 737-related data for your cockpit

Comment: Any way to mention US?  I'd hate to ask the same question, as it is a good one, I've been trying to find a real simulator for a while

Comment: @KORD4me: Flight Experience mentions [Coming to Boston this summer](http://www.flightexperience.com/our-stores/) but not which year or even which hemisphere. :)

Comment: I did read that, still hoping for something closer to Chicago!!

Comment: If you're ever in London, http://www.virtual-aerospace.com/product-category/flight-experiences/?gclid=CMas8MvGqL0CFa3LtAod-FgAAQ

Comment: @KORD4me See my answer about the Delta museum at ATL.

Comment: @KORD4me, not close to Chicago, but the Hiller Aviation Museum in San Carlos, CA has a (older) 737 cockpit to view (open for entry on certain days) and has a 747 nose section (including cockpit) to enter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cotswold Airport, near the village of Kemble in Gloucestershire, England.

Cotswolds landing strip, has become the busiest aviation scrapyard in the world.

[image]

[image]

Usually the cockpit parts are taken out before they end up there, but you never know; you may get lucky and they grant you access for a day. I don't see why not!

Chevron Aircraft Maintenance Ltd is responsible for the dismantling of all Boeing 737 series aircraft.

Answer (score 10):

There is a company called [Flight Experience](http://www.flightexperience.com/) which builds 737 simulators and offers their use to the public. These are fully certified simulators and are frequently used by commercial pilots for currency training.

Their closest location to London appears to be in Paris.

I had an opportunity to fly one of their simulators a few years ago, and it was a lot of fun. We spent some time doing landings at the old Kai Tak airport in Hong Kong.

Comment: There are many more such companies.

Comment: @JanHudec Can you please name some?

Comment: @Farhan: Unfortunately not one relevant for England.

Comment: @JanHudec: How about in the US?

Comment: @Farhan: Even less:-(.

Comment: @JanHudec Found one, but in [Canada](http://uflysimulator.ca/) They have a month long wait time to register.

Comment: Flight Safety locations used to have Familiarization classes on some commercial airlines at their locations.  I spent time in DC-9 simulator a few years back while I as attending my recurrent session.

Comment: @farhan: Flight Experience has a location in the Boston MA area.  There was talk a year or two ago about them opening a location in Orlando FL, but I don't think anything ever materialized.

Answer (score 6):

I noticed that someone in the comments had asked about the U.S., too. [Delta's aviation museum in Atlanta](http://www.deltamuseum.org/) does offer the ability to rent an hour in an old 737-200 simulator. This is a full-motion pilot-training simulator. [Their website](http://www.deltamuseum.org/exhibits) claims that it's the only one open to the public in the U.S. It costs about $400 USD for an hour.

Comment: And it was quite fun, though the graphics are from 2002 at best.

Comment: @zymhan Yes the graphics are indeed old. But then so is the plane it simulates. That plane was _retired_ from the fleet 18 years ago. I wouldn't be surprised if the simulator was built in the 1990s.

Answer (score 3):

[Bournemouth aviation museum?](http://www.bournemouthecho.co.uk/news/10878747.Axed_Palmair_jet_makes_its_final_landing_at_aviation_museum/)

> BOURNEMOUTH’S popular aviation museum has a new addition – of a more recent vintage.
>
> The distinctive exhibit is an old Palmair jet, a familiar sight at the airport until the carrier closed three years ago.
>
> The **Boeing 737-200** carried tens of thousands of holidaymakers from Bournemouth Airport, before being replaced by a more modern plane.
>
> The front half of the white fuselage was unveiled at the museum along Parley Lane last week.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're in the South West then take a look at the [full motion flight simulator](https://www.jetexsimulation.co.uk/) at Jet-Ex Simulation. It's a full 737 cockpit on a moog motion base with 6-dof. They're based in Frome, Somerset.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little bit of an "outside of the box" answer, and I won't be accepting it. I'm just sharing it so there are more ideas of places to do this.

[Virgin Experience Days](http://www.virginexperiencedays.co.uk/boeing-737-flight-simulator-15-minute-flight-sp8) offer 15 minutes of 737 simulator time to newbies for £24.50 in London. I guess I could just tell them I don't want to fly, I just want to "play with the buttons" :P

Answer (score 2):

British Airways' flight training program provides public access to their [full motion simulators](http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/baft/fly-a-simulator/fly-a-simulator-public/fly-a-simulator-public).

You can book a [one hour training session](http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/baft/fly-a-simulator/fly-a-simulator-public/booking-your-experience/booking-your-experience) in their 737-400 simulator.

In my opinion, well worth the money, since its a professional and I stress again **full motion simulator**. In fact, its the same one BA uses to train their own pilots.

They are located in [Cranebank](https://www.britishairways.com/en-fr/baft/our-location/our-location).

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be [SimSpot](http://www.simspot.co.uk/simulator-experiences.htm). This way you can get a real look and feel.

I have been past this spot time after time as is in the Cineworld but never ventured in. It's now on my checklist of things to do 2015 :)

Comment: @Farhan thanks for the edit still quite new on here :)

Comment: You are welcome. *We all are learning here.* If you need more help, don't hesitate to join in [chat (link down on every page)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar). You'll find many people willing to help.